# How to test connection between asp net core application with Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing

Tags: asp.net-core, integration-testing

I have multiple services and I want to use Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing to test connection between them. I use Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing for integration test for each service and I try to use it for multiple service scenario. But I run into issue how to do it

This is my test:

```
    public class Web1ApplicationFactory : WebApplicationFactory<Startup1>
    {
        protected override IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder() =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup1>();
                });
    }

    public class Web2ApplicationFactory : WebApplicationFactory<Startup2>
    {
        protected override IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder() =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup2>();
                });
    }

    [Trait("Category", "E2E")]
    public abstract class E2ETestsBase
    {
        protected readonly HttpClient client1;
        protected readonly HttpClient client2;

        protected E2ETestsBase()
        {
            client1 = new Web1ApplicationFactory().CreateClient();
            client2 = new Web2ApplicationFactory().CreateClient();
        }
    }


    public class CreateIncidentTests : E2ETestsBase
    {
        [Fact]
        public async Task Should_PassFrom1TO2()
        {
            // Arrange
            var id = MyId.New();
            var body = new CreateRequest(id, "sample");
            var requestContent = new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(body), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            // Act
            var response1 = await client1.PostAsync("Create", requestContent);
            var response2 = await client2.GetAsync($"{id.IdValue}");
           
            // Assert
            Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.OK, response1.StatusCode);
            Assert.Equal("application/json; charset=utf-8", response1.Content.Headers.ContentType?.ToString());
            Assert.Equal($"\"{id.IdValue}\"", await response1.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

            Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.OK, response2.StatusCode);
        }
    }
```

Web1Application post data to Web2Application in some cases via HttpClient.PostAsync in development enviroment to `https://localhost:156123`. But how to post from Web1Application to Web2Application in tests? There is no port it runs in test process. Is there a way how to test scenario like this? Or I have to use selenium or something like that?